# Автозапуск приложения

Tags: java, android, автозагрузка

Столкнулся со стандартной проблемой: запуск приложения сразу после включения телефона. Все советы либо устарели, либо не работают. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Дан файл MainActivity, который должен открываться сразу после разблокировки телефона. Как это сделать?)

Comment: Так после включения аппарата или каждой разблокировки экрана?

Comment: Каждой разблокировки

Comment: Тогда что в этой проблеме стандартного? Это не типичное поведение для "простых смертных" приложений. Тут нужен либо рут, либо писать собственный кейгуард/лаунчер. Или вы имеете в виду, что на устройстве должно быть только ваше приложение и ничего другого (типа терминала) - тогда уточните вопрос и поищите пока по запросу "android kiosk mode"

Comment: А можно ли из Service открыть Активити?

Comment: Можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588962, но: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts. Плюс далеко не везде ваш сервис будет "бессмертным". Ещё можно ловить разблокировку: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225681, но опять же все решения теряют актуальность к последним версиям системы.